# How to substitute a value that is not found in a list (index out of range) with 0 for a sum

Tags: python-3.x

How do I sum an index that does not exist with 0. I mean substituting the value not found. The program has the problem that when I select less choices that expected for the sum the program write me `index out of range` and I would like to substitute that values with 0.
How I do that if I want to sum 10 values or less and I select less?

```
scores = []
result_f = open("Tienda.txt")

for line in result_f:
    (name,score) = line.split()
    scores.append(float(score))

result_f.close()
Label(app,text="Su total es").pack()
r=int(scores[0])
w=int(scores[1])      

a=int(scores[2])
d=int(scores[3])
g=int(r+w+a+d)
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum 10 values or less:

```
g = sum(scores[:10])
```

Comment: I want to put that sum in a label inside a tkinter windows how i do that, that number get label in the tkinter windows because when i do it it just disappear and is not shown.